# How can I recognize wanted criminals in Godlike Burger?

Tags: godlike-burger

There's this event in Godlike Burger where your restaurant may sometimes be visited by *wanted criminals* that you can kill for a money reward. Problem is, I don't see any distinguishable marks as the *critic* customers have (monocle, moustache).

So, how do I recognize them? I though it might have something to do with the color pattern of the clothing, but the customers seem to vary in colors anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they just look "different" that the normal Customers, usually a darker color, I've found some examples showing them:

- [Tatola (birds): Darker grey](https://youtu.be/EiVRlGrK4Cc?t=1916)
- [Tarat (rats): Darker grey](https://youtu.be/EiVRlGrK4Cc?t=1805)
- Bradig (corn): This one has a brown suite and a black hat, see screenshot
- Nublshar (teeth with horns): Darker grey,  see screenshot
- Zeikelik (one-eyed): Different colored hat, see screenshot

Here in red Circles you'll see Criminals, in Green their "normal" appearance.
[image: screenshot with criminals]

Generally, you'll get a notification `criminal is arriving`, and also another notification, `Money rewad received`, when you kill one.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thanks for the thorough answer :)